# Stock martket reductions in a recession

Tags: stocks, recession

Can somebody give examples of how much different stock markets dropped during recessions, in percentage terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [web site](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/37740147/ns/business-stocks_and_economy/t/historic-bear-markets/#.XmQO69QrKXY)  provides stats for bear markets during the past 90 years.

Here's a chart of 100 years of the DJIA along with recessions.  You can go to the web site and if you hover the cursor, you can see the prices.  For more precise numbers you can download historical numbers from Yahoo Finance or similar:

[image]

Comment: Might be worth differentiating recessions from bear markets for the OP.